# Set values for all records in a Kdb table based on values of other columns

Tags: kdb

I need to perform a global update on a KDB table to update two columns. For the FirstName column, I want to remove it's value for records which have empty string in the SecondName column, and for the FullName column I want to replace an encoded delimiter with a space for all rows in the table.

These need not be done in a single update statement if that helps.

```
update
    FirstName:$[SecondName like ""; FirstName; ""],
    FullName[FullName; "&nbsp;"; " "]
    from table
    }
```

I'm struggling with the syntax - the above is my best attempt but it doesn't work.

Comment: If it helps, think of references to column names like vectors, not scalars...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to achieve that in a sinlge update statement:

```
q) update FirstName:?[SecondName like ""; SecondName;FirstName], FullName:ssr[;"&nbsp;"; " "]@'FullName from table
```

Comment: Blimey - that was quick :) I only refreshed the page 10 minutes ago and didn't refresh again before posting my own solution - yours is definitely nicer than mine though, thanks!

Comment: Glad it helped.

Answer (score 2):

For your update for the FirstName you need a ? rather than a $ as the Execution control operator.  As it does the execution with a list rather than an atom.
For the FullName you will need to use ssr, which finds where string has "&nbsp" and replaces it with " "

Which would give the following:

```
q)tab:([]FirstName:("aa";"cc");SecondName:("";"dd");FullName:("aa&nbsp;";"cc&nbsp;dd"))
q)update FirstName:?[SecondName like ""; count[FirstName]#enlist""; FirstName],FullName:ssr[; "&nbsp;";" "]each FullName from tab
FirstName SecondName FullName
-----------------------------
""        ""         "aa "
"cc"      "dd"       "cc dd"
```

Hope this answers your question.

Regards,
Sander

Comment: Thanks very much Sander - seems there are many different ways to achieve this result. I have something that works now so won't waste time trying every solution offered but I reallly appreciate your input :)

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend to do it in two steps

```
//create table with mock data
table: ([]FirstName: ("aaa";"ccc"); SecondName: ("bbb";""); FullName: ("aaa bbb";"ccc "));
//step1: set First to "" whenever SecondName is ""
table: update FirstName: (count i)#enlist"" from table where SecondName like "";
//step2: replace spaces in FullName
table: update FullName: ssr[;"&nbsp;";" "] each FullName from table;
```

Comment: Hah - very similar to mine - amazed at how many responses I got so quickly - thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 1):

Got it I think:

```
table:update FirstName:(count i)#enlist "" from table where SecondName like "";
table:update FullName:{ ssr[x; "&nbsp;"; " "] } each FullName from table where FullName like "*&nbsp;*";
```